# PHP make options clickable links in select tag

Tags: php, select, foreach

I'm trying to make the options in the select tag clickable links, but I'm not able to click anything before the browser redirects to the first value it gets from the mysql array.

```
<select name="recipient" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3"id="choice" onchange="location.href=this.value">
<?php 
foreach($all_users as $user):
 ?>
<option selected='' value="<?=$user['id']; ?>"><?= $user['firstname'] . ' ' . $user['lastname']; ?>
</option>                                   
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iBIk.jpg)

Comment: Post the rendered HTML please

Comment: `onchange="location.href=this.value"` literally means "when this changes perform a redirect". If you don't want that, remove it.

Comment: I kinda figured about that :/ what I want is to click an option and then be redirected to a specific url.

Comment: So.... is it working or not? It is redirecting according to your question. But is it just not redirecting to where you want it to go?

Comment: An `<option>` cannot contain a link. This code should do what you want, except that the option’s `value` should be a URL instead of just the user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, what is your question exactly, but try my code hopefully you will get something

```
<select id="select-opt">
    <option value="https://www.google.com/">Google</option>
    <option value="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</option>
    <option value="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</option>
</select>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).on('change', '#select-opt', function (e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        window.location.href=value;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I needed to click an option and then redirect to a specific url generated with a specific id value which is pulled from a database. Your code did exactly that so thank you so much!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).